# How to sum all column values in multi dimensional array JavaScript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I add all the columnar values by associative key? Note that key sets are dynamic.

```
var a= [
  [100.7, 100.7, 100.7],
  [24.1, 0, 24.1]
]
```

Desired result:

```
[124.1,100.7,124.7]
```

my code

```
var add=0;

  var aee=[];
    for(var i=0 ;i<a.length;i++)
        {
            for(var j=0;j<a[i].length;j++)
                {
                    add=add+a[j][i];
                }
            aee.push(add);
            add=0;
        }
    console.log(aee);
```

error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: You should show us what you had tried. This is not a coding writing platform.

Comment: use `Array#map` and `Array#reduce` methods

Comment: Why is the first column `100.7 + 24.1 = 124.1` and the third `100.7 + 24.1 = 124.7`? Shouldn't they both be `124.8`?

Answer (score 3):

This is how you can do it.

```js
console.log([[100.7, 100.7, 100.7],[24.1, 0, 24.1]].reduce((r, a) => r.map((b, i) => a[i] + b)));
```